# R MongoDB command errors crash R session

Tags: r, debugging, mongodb, malloc, runtime-error

This is not a question but a request to help diagnose and fix a problem.

Using the latest (1.0.2) version of `rmongodb` the following code crashes the session of R 2.15.2 on Mac OS X. The code works in R 2.15.1 on a different Mac OS X machine.

```
library(rmongodb)
mongo <- mongo.create('127.0.0.1', db='test')
print(mongo.is.connected(mongo))
mongo.find.one(mongo, 'unknown')
```

The output is:

```
> library(rmongodb)
rmongodb package (mongo-r-driver) loaded
Use 'help("mongo")' to get started.

> mongo <- mongo.create('127.0.0.1', db='test')
> print(mongo.is.connected(mongo))
[1] TRUE
> mongo.find.one(mongo, 'unknown')
R(60519) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5fbfce10: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

The same type of crash happens if you pass a non-existent command to MongoDB. Again, this used to work under R 2.15.1.

```
> library(rmongodb)
> mongo <- mongo.create('127.0.0.1', db='test')
> mongo.command(mongo, 'test', list(isMaster=1))
    ismaster : 8     true
    maxBsonObjectSize : 16   16777216
    ok : 1   1.000000
> mongo.command(mongo, 'test', list(fake=1))
R(66743) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5fbfde20: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I have [created an issue](https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/rmongodb/issues/11) in the `rmongodb` project and would appreciate any help scoping & validating the problem to enable the package developer to hone in on what needs fixing or, perhaps, prove that it is not an `rmongodb` issue but some strange interaction in my environment.

I will accept an answer from someone who runs the code either on 2.15.1 and 2.15.2 on Mac OS X or on 2.15.2 on Mac OS X and at least one other environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the package author](https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/rmongodb/issues/11#issuecomment-11476965) this issue is fixed on GitHub but CRAN hasn't been updated.